# Wireless with 802.11r, 802.11k and 802.1x

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware, 802.1x

I was recommended to seek for assistance here from the Networking/Stack Exchange site towards OS X queries, do hope someone has the answers.

Have El Capitan on a testing iMac and deploying 802.11r/k with FT-dot1x from a Cisco WLC showed no issues with wireless connectivity. Though one client showed up with a MacBook with wireless issues. Turns out the OS X version on the Mac is 10.7 "Lion"...that is apparently old and obviously doesn't support 802.11r/k. Found a good page within Mac support for iOS [(Wi-Fi network roaming with 802.11k, 802.11r, and 802.11v on iOS)](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202628) but not a support matrix for OS X.

Is there any available support matrix/table/information for listing which versions of OS X hardware and operating system versions towards 802.11r/k support?

Comment: This thread is looking a bit sad... can anyone mention what is the oldest version of OS X they've had working with 802.11r?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's not going to be a way to support those standards without upgrading the Mac OS X version.

Comment: That could be the case though it would be good to find out which version of Os X starts supporting these 2008 standards. We found out Lion didn't and El Capitan did.

Answer (score 4):

As of 10.13.6 macOS doesn't support 802.11 *v*, *k* or *r* but interoperates with APs that have it enabled.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206207

https://framebyframewifi.net/2017/08/20/macos-wi-fi-roaming/

EDIT: No change (e.g. no support) in 10.14 Mojave.

EDIT 2: Still no support in 10.15.

Comment: Thanks for this!!! I'm currently looking to buy a mesh wifi kit and was afraid my Macs would have a problem connecting to them.

Comment: Not in 11.0 either...

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for anyone who is interested.

According to this thread, no support for 802.11r/k for Os X up to 10.9:

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12314591/8021r-and-fast-roaming

Comment: According to that, OS X 10.9 doesn't support 802.11r mixed-mode, but 10.9.2 does. But I don't see anything about it in the update notes for either [10.9.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202891) or [10.9.2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204448). I'd like to see specific confirmation...

Answer (score 0):

Because the answers on this page are woefully out of date, but this page still ranks highly on Google, I thought I'd provide some modern information. Short answer is that Macs using "Apple Silicon" support k, r, and v. I don't know what 802.11x is.

**802.11k and r**

- iPhone 4s and later
- iPad Pro and later
- iPad Air and later
- iPad mini and later
- iPad (3rd generation) and later
- iPod touch (5th generation) and later
- Mac computers with Apple silicon

**Adaptive 802.11r**

- iPhone 6s and later
- iPad Pro and later
- iPad Air (3rd generation) and later
- iPad (5th generation) and later
- iPod touch (7th generation)
- Mac computers with Apple silicon

**802.11v**

- iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, and later
- iPad Pro and later
- iPad Air and later
- iPad mini 2 and later
- iPad (5th generation) and later
- iPod touch (6th generation) and later
- Mac computers with Apple silicon

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202628